# How do I bulk or batch update multiple fields or columns with multiple conditions or criteria with a single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

This is what my table looks like before the query.

```
cid  | purl      | purl_full
----------------------------
2050 | dingo     | http://dingo.domain.com
2050 | wombat    | http://wombat.domain.com
2050 | platypus  | http://platypus.domain.com
2050 | koala     | http://koala.domain.com
2050 | dingo1    | http://dingo1.domain.com
2050 | wombat1   | http://wombat1.domain.com
2050 | platypus1 | http://platypus1.domain.com
2050 | koala1    | http://koala1.domain.com
2050 | dingo     | tempurl
2050 | wombat    | tempurl
2050 | platypus  | tempurl
2050 | koala     | tempurl
```

This is what it should look like after the query.

```
cid  | purl      | purl_full
----------------------------
2050 | dingo     | http://dingo.domain.com
2050 | wombat    | http://wombat.domain.com
2050 | platypus  | http://platypus.domain.com
2050 | koala     | http://koala.domain.com
2050 | dingo1    | http://dingo1.domain.com
2050 | wombat1   | http://wombat1.domain.com
2050 | platypus1 | http://platypus1.domain.com
2050 | koala1    | http://koala1.domain.com
2050 | dingo2    | http://dingo2.domain.com
2050 | wombat2   | http://wombat2.domain.com
2050 | platypus2 | http://platypus2.domain.com
2050 | koala2    | http://koala2.domain.com
```

This is what it ends up looking like after the query.

```
cid  | purl      | purl_full
----------------------------
2050 | dingo     | http://dingo.domain.com
2050 | wombat    | http://wombat.domain.com
2050 | platypus  | http://platypus.domain.com
2050 | koala     | http://koala.domain.com
2050 | dingo1    | http://dingo1.domain.com
2050 | wombat1   | http://wombat1.domain.com
2050 | platypus1 | http://platypus1.domain.com
2050 | koala1    | http://koala1.domain.com
2050 | dingo2    | 
2050 | wombat2   | 
2050 | platypus2 | 
2050 | koala2    |
```

Here is the query i'm using.

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_data SET 
purl = (CASE 
WHEN (purl = 'dingo' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'dingo2' 
WHEN (purl = 'wombat' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'wombat2' 
WHEN (purl = 'platypus' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'platypus2' 
WHEN (purl = 'koala' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'koala2' 
END), 
purl_full = (CASE 
WHEN (purl = 'dingo' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://dingo2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'wombat' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://wombat2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'platypus' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://platypus2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'koala' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://koala2.domain.com' 
END) 
WHERE (purl IN ('dingo', 'wombat', 'platypus', 'koala') AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050);
```

So it updates the one field, but not the other field. It just blanks out the second field for some reason.

This is even worse:

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_data SET 
purl = CASE 
WHEN (purl = 'dingo' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'dingo2' 
WHEN (purl = 'wombat' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'wombat2' 
WHEN (purl = 'platypus' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'platypus2' 
WHEN (purl = 'koala' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'koala2' 
END, 
purl_full = CASE 
WHEN (purl = 'dingo' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://dingo2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'wombat' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://wombat2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'platypus' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://platypus2.domain.com' 
WHEN (purl = 'koala' AND purl_full = 'tempurl' AND cid = 2050) THEN 'http://koala2.domain.com' 
END;
```

Also tried this and didn't work (making purl a unique name) (again it only updates purl, but not purl_full, or rather it updates it but makes it empty):

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_data 
SET purl = CASE purl 
WHEN 'temp_dingo' THEN 'dingo' 
WHEN 'temp_wombat' THEN 'wombat' 
WHEN 'temp_platypus' THEN 'platypus' 
WHEN 'temp_koala' THEN 'koala' 
END, 
purl_full = CASE purl 
WHEN 'temp_dingo' THEN 'http://dingo.domain.com' 
WHEN 'temp_wombat' THEN 'http://wombat.domain.com' 
WHEN 'temp_platypus' THEN 'http://platypus.domain.com' 
WHEN 'temp_koala' THEN 'http://koala.domain.com' 
END 
WHERE (purl IN ('temp_dingo', 'temp_wombat', 'temp_platypus', 'temp_koala') AND cid = 2050);
```

As a side question, how does it do the updating? does it do all of column 1 then all of column 2, or does it do both columns at the same time then go to next record and do both columns at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working. I needed to change the purl name in the second SET CASEs to what it was changing to, not to the original name. So that kind of answers that side question whether it does it column at a time or row at a time.

```
UPDATE localhost_campaigns.list_data 
SET purl = CASE purl 
WHEN 'temp_dingo' THEN 'dingo' 
WHEN 'temp_wombat' THEN 'wombat' 
WHEN 'temp_platypus' THEN 'platypus' 
WHEN 'temp_koala' THEN 'koala' 
END, 
purl_full = CASE purl 
WHEN 'dingo' THEN 'http://dingo.domain.com' 
WHEN 'wombat' THEN 'http://wombat.domain.com' 
WHEN 'platypus' THEN 'http://platypus.domain.com' 
WHEN 'koala' THEN 'http://koala.domain.com' 
END 
WHERE (purl IN ('temp_dingo', 'temp_wombat', 'temp_platypus', 'temp_koala') AND cid = 2050);
```